# How to charge an iPhone on a Windows PC without Installing iTunes

Tags: windows, iphone, itunes, windows-server-2008

I want to be able to charge my iPhone on my work computer, which is running Windows Server 2008 SP1 64-Bit. When I plug the iPhone in with the USB cable, it will not charge. Windows attempts to locate a driver for the device but only comes up with a generic Camera device and even if I allow that to be installed, the iPhone still does not charge. I have checked the computer's BIOS settings and did not find anything relating to power on the USB devices. I also tried this on ports at the back of the computer in addition to those on the front. The PC is a Dell Optiplex 780.

As far as I can tell USB devices do not charge unless Windows has installed an appropriate driver. Since it is a work computer I do not want to install iTunes which does include a driver. I have a workaround that I will post as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This workaround allows the iPhone to charge without a full install of iTunes but it's still a bit of a pain as you can't download the driver directly as far as I can tell.

- Download [iTunes64Setup.exe](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1047) (about 95MB). If you are on a 32-bit version of Windows download [iTunesSetup.exe](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/)
- Use an archive tool like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to open the file as an archive. For 7-Zip, right click on iTunes64Setup.exe and select **7-Zip->Open Archive**
- Extract the **AppleMobileDeviceSupport64.msi** file (about 10MB) to a temporary directory. I presume the 32 bit version is just called AppleMobileDeviceSupport.msi.
- Run the installer and follow the prompts.

After this my iPhone charges successfully. A bit irritating that you still end up having to download the large iTunesSetup.exe but the best I could come up with!

Comment: Do you have the Desktop Experience feature installed?  I followed your directions (windows server 2008 x64) and did not have any luck.  These led me to wonder if I needed the "photo management" portion of Windows, since that is what kicks in by default when I plug my iPhone into my XP box.

Comment: I do have the Desktop Experience feature installed now but I'm fairly sure I didn't at the time I made this post. Unfortunately I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 7.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Half way through the install my phone started charging - then the install failed and I had to roll it back but iPhone is still charging! And I don't have the Desktop Experience feature installed.

Comment: On Win8 worked.  There was an error from mobile MSI about unable to start service, clicked 'Ignore', rebooted, now my iPhone charges.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get phone to charge by installing Desktop Experience, then installing the driver using device manager.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to shut down the phone as you're plugging it into the USB port.  It will charge if the phone is off. If you plug it in while it's off it will automatically turn on.  As long as its off it will charge.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to charge is without installing anything and that is..

1. Connect your iphone to any win system. If the phone is shut down before plugging to usb, the phone will power up.
2. Continue holding the shutdown button on iphone and let it switch off.
3. Plug your iphone back on after 30 mins and it will be almost charged up.

No install needed.

I have tested this on the latest win2012 server as well.